# Skype Echo Bot for NodeJS: Messages Not Appearing in Skype App

Tags: node.js, bots, skypedeveloper

I am following this [Echo Bot Tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs/tutorials/simple-nodejs), and have gone through all of the basic steps regarding setup and registration. I am following the steps (near the bottom) regarding local testing, and have been using ngrok successfully.

I was able to add my Skype Bot as a contact, and I also have the latest version of the Skype app (Mac). When I send a message to the bot via the Skype app, I see the message appear in the debug notes in my terminal window. So I know that the messages I type are coming through.

I also see this:

```
skype-sdk.MessagingServiceClientV2 Sending message to 8:username with content Hey 8:username. Thank you for your message: "test".
```

However, I do not see any kind of reply in my Skype application. My expectation is that the bot would echo back my message to me.

My questions are:

1) When testing locally using the ngrok method described in the tutorial, should I be able to see activity from the Skype bot (in terms of messages *to* me)?

2) I am guessing this may be some an authentication issue? How can I best troubleshoot things, and get the Skype bot to actually respond in the Skype app?

---

I feel like I am incredibly close to getting this working, in that the messages I send are coming through... but the messages I expect from the Skype bot are *not* coming through. Any help or ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix, and posting it here should anyone else run into the same issue.

During the setup process, when I was using the Application Registration Portal, I selected the wrong string as my Application Secret.

Originally, I clicked on **Generate New Key Pair**, which resulted in a new entry appearing in the admin labeled *Private Key*. I used this string as my App Secret.

However, it appears that what I should have done was click on **Generate New Password** and used *that string instead**. Just gave it a try, and my bot is now responding back to me locally (in the Skype app), when testing with ngrok.

I think this particular distinction could have been made clearer in the documentation, as I lost a great deal of time due to this one oversight. Oh well, at least I can start developing now...